# NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Tags: class, undefined

When I type it into both Visual Studio Code and Jupiter, this code will not run, and I get the "NameError: name 'User' is not defined" error message.  Yet when I copy and paste the EXACT same code from the author's website, it runs perfectly. I've read everything I could find online and in Python 3.9 documentation and can't figure out why. Here is the code:

class User():

```
"""Represent a simple user profile."""
    
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
    """Initialize the user."""
    self.first_name = first_name.title()
    self.last_name = last_name.title()
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    self.location = location.title()

def describe_user(self):
    """Display a summary of the user's information."""
    print(f"\n{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
    print(f"  Username: {self.username}")
    print(f"  Email: {self.email}")
    print(f"  Location: {self.location}")

def greet_user(self):
    """Display a personalized greeting to the user."""
    print(f"\nWelcome back, {self.username}!")
john = User('john', 'bassett', 'Jack', 'jack@me.com', 'L.A.')
john.describe_user()
john.greet_user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess it would be a formatting issue. Whitespace (tabs and spaces) are meaningful in Python. Your formatting is off in the StackOverflow post here, in that the "class User" line is outside the preformatted code block, and all the class's methods are indented at the wrong level. You want something like:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self):
       return
    def another_method(self):
       return
john = User('john')
```

Comment: You were right! I started from the bottom up instead of the top down and that helped me find the spaces/indents that weren't right.  Thank you for taking the time to reply. I don't even want to admit  how long I struggled to find what was wrong with it.   :)